# Paging not working when loadonce:true in jqGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid-asp.net

In jqGrid have property **loadonce:true** then i am getting only first page records. how can i get second and third page records.

**code:**

```
$(function () {

        $("#pendingAppgrid").jqGrid({
            colNames: ['Name', 'Email'],
            colModel: [
                        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', sortable: true, align: 'left', width: '200',
                            editable: false, edittype: 'text',search:true

                        },

                         { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', sortable: false, align: 'left', width: '200',
                             editable: false, edittype: 'text',search:true
                         },  
                  ],
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            sortname: 'Name',
            rowNum: 15,
            rowList: [10, 20, 25],
            sortorder: "desc",
            height: 345,
            ignoreCase: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            caption: 'Pending Approvals',
            width: 660,
            url: "@Url.Content("~/Home/PendingApprovals")",
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            loadonce: true
        })
        jQuery("#pendingAppgrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOnEnter: true, enableClear: false });

    });
```

**Server code**

```
public ActionResult PendingApprovals(int page, int rows, string sidx, string sord)
        {

            //return View(GetPendingApprovals());
            int currentPage = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int totalRecords = 0;
            List<ViewModels.Channel.UserChannels> lTemChannel = new List<ViewModels.Channel.UserChannels>();
            List<ViewModels.Channel.UserChannels> lstChannel = new List<ViewModels.Channel.UserChannels>();
            lTemChannel = GetPendingApprovals();
            foreach (ViewModels.Channel.UserChannels cha in lTemChannel)
            {
                ViewModels.Channel.UserChannels channelWithLogo = new ViewModels.Channel.UserChannels();
                channelWithLogo.ID = cha.ID;
                channelWithLogo.Name = cha.Name;
                channelWithLogo.Email = cha.Email;

                lstChannel.Add(channelWithLogo);
            }
            totalRecords = lstChannel.Count;
            var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalRecords / (float)rows);
                lstChannel = lstChannel.ToList<ViewModels.Channel.UserChannels>();

            IPagedList<ViewModels.Channel.UserChannels> ilstChannel;
            switch (sord)
            {
                case "desc":
                    ilstChannel = lstChannel.OrderByDescending(m => m.Name).ToPagedList(page, rows);
                    break;
                case "asc":
                    ilstChannel = lstChannel.OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToPagedList(page, rows);
                    break;
                default:
                    ilstChannel = lstChannel.OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToPagedList(page, rows);
                    break;
            }

            var data = ilstChannel;

            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page,
                records = totalRecords,

                rows = (from m in data
                        select new
                        {

                            id = m.ChannelID,
                            cell = new object[]
                           {
                               m.Name,
                               m.Email
                           }
                        }).ToArray()
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here i am getting only first page records. i have more pages. search functionality working fine. problem is i am only first page records. not getting other pages records. how can i get another page records. Please help this.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `loadonce:true` jqGrid change the datatype parameters to '**local**' after the first load of data from the grid. All next grid reloading (sorting, paging, filtering) works local. If you want refresh the grid data from the server one more time you should set datatype to its original value ('**json**' or 'xml'). For example:

```
$("#pendingAppgrid").setGridParam({datatype:'json', page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Please visit [http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) for more details of the jqGrid options.

Comment: i did same thing. changed datatype='local'. and placed what you given code inside the function means after "filterToolbar". but i am not getting.

Comment: @Ram, you don't need to change datatype to local, jqGrid itself did it after first load, when you have option loadonce as true. You have to add this code in pager, Please post paging code.

Comment: ok. please can you post properly how to do paging for this. Here i am getting first page records only. if i change page no:2 in footer section, its not displaying second page records.

Comment: @Ram, solution depends on your paging code, please post it in question, so that exact problem is solved. Generic solution might not help you & might waste our time.

Comment: @Ram, Exactly this happens, page-2 doesn't display since "loadonce" option set datatype to local after first load & server-side hit is restricted but it can perform filter on local data, that's what I want to convey very first in answer. Try adding that code onclick of paging button(button that takes you to next page, it must be in #pager div) and replace page number by required page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is complex, read all even the comentaries, you need to recover the actual page of the Jgrid with:

```
var llPage = $("#listaCfdi").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'page');
//1 but this page is not the page of the "pager" and is before to call the method that fill the jgrid again
//, so the page will change after to fill the grid, you must call "onPaging" to fill again the Jgrid, like this:

//2
, onPaging: function (pgButton) {
        FillAgainJgrid();
    }
```

and in FillAgainJgrid(); (in this example) you need to call again other method that will have the real page of the "pager" that the user want, in example, the jgrid is in the page:5, and you want the las page, something like page:15, so the second call will have the real page, that the importan thing of the second call. Only it needs two calls to be sure that the page is the correct. And in this example, FillAgainJgridEnsure(); is exact to FillAgainJgrid(); except that doesnt have onPaging again

```
//3. In the server side, the page you are passed to the method only will work in the first call, because have all the data
//, and all the pages, but in example in the second call with the page:3, the jgrid will lost all the real information about the size of page, and only will return page:3 like if was the only one, you need a trick like this
//, (they are two list, one with all the data, and then you will get only the page you need, and the second list will have all the other rows in empty
//, so in this way you will get always all the correct rows number of the query, you need Concat in this example because we need all the rows, and if you are filled with dataset, in the sql server you need to use union all) :

ENTIDADES.Cfdi[] resultadoDos = null; //This is the class to provide the correct number of rows

        //this is the query that always will have all the data
        resultado = new CLASES.DAL.Facturacion().ObtenerCfdiDisponibles(criteriosBusqueda);
        if (resultado.Length > 100)
        {
            resultadoDos = new ENTIDADES.Cfdi[resultado.Length - 100];
            for (int i = 0; i < resultado.Length - 100; i++)
            {
                ENTIDADES.Cfdi referenciaVacia = new ENTIDADES.Cfdi();
                resultadoDos[i] = referenciaVacia;
            }
        }
//Paging here, in the server size
        resultado = resultado.OrderBy(p => p.Cliente).Skip(((Convert.ToInt32(_Pagina)) - 1) * 100).Take(100).ToArray();
        if (resultadoDos != null) //if there are more that 100 rows, in this example
        {//concat the page and the fill data empty 
            resultado = resultado.Concat(resultadoDos).OrderByDescending(x => x.Cliente).ToArray();
        }

        regresar = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultado);
```

//Note, dont forget to OrderByDescending (in this example), because it will show first the data that have the rows filled, 100 is the size of rows of the page.

Omar Romero Mexico City